# Docker duplicate layers being pushed

Tags: docker

I am still trying to wrap my head around docker. I've got the hang of most of the stuff when working locally. But now I want to push an image created using docker-compose build to aws ect. I did this last week and it worked well, and have not made huge changes to the project since.

Now when I push I get repeats in the layers being pushed:

```
9cc8258cd405: Pushed 
75573d8d8f3b: Pushed 
05fe91a612c7: Pushed 
cf10d0792ab2: Pushed 
3491c0d358f9: Pushing [======>                                            ]  116.8MB/869.8MB
3491c0d358f9: Pushing [======>                                            ]  117.3MB/869.8MB
3491c0d358f9: Pushing [======>                                            ]  117.9MB/869.8MB
3491c0d358f9: Pushing [======>                                            ]  118.5MB/869.8MB
3491c0d358f9: Pushing [======>                                            ]    119MB/869.8MB
3491c0d358f9: Pushing [===========>                                       ]  196.4MB/869.8MB
73fc8bce5073: Layer already exists 
54d95b300b59: Layer already exists 
b1638a94bc26: Layer already exists 
0f093e2a0b2a: Layer already exists 
9df2ff4714f2: Layer already exists 
c30dae2762bd: Layer already exists 
43701cc70351: Layer already exists 
e14378b596fb: Layer already exists 
a2e66f6c6f5f: Layer already exists
```

I am not where to look for the issue. My docker-compose and Dockerfile are the same as I used last week when it worked. Any help pointing in a direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's duplicate layers and not just messed up terminal output? What if it's pushing chunks of the layer in parallel because it's large enough to warrant that? Does it push properly?

Comment: The `docker` command-line tool does a number of things to try and do this efficiently, so you may be seeing an artifact of it here. So long as you get the expected result, it's just a quirk of the presentation.

Comment: Yes I thinks its possible, but with all 869.8MB and at different stages I thought I would double check. I aborted the push and restarted and then there was only one, and it worked. So maybe it was just terminal.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the clarifications man!